# What is the difference between releasing and autoreleasing?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, autorelease

I still have some unclear understand about release and autorelease. What are the difference between both of them? I have this code. For facebook connection. I crash it sometimes when I go to Facebook login, I doubting maybe it is because I don't release the object nicely.? Thanks for any helps

```
if (_session.isConnected) {
        [_session logout];
    } else {
        FBLoginDialog* dialog = [[[FBLoginDialog alloc] initWithSession:_session] autorelease];
        [dialog show];
    }
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The [Memory Management Programming Guide for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447) will soon be your best friend. In brief, object instances in Cocoa are memory managed using reference counting (unless, of course you're using garbage collection on OS X). An object indicates that it wants to 'retain' an ownership interest in an other instance--keep it from being deallocated--by sending it a `-retain` message. An object indicates that it wants to release that interest by sending the other instance a `-release` message. If the number of objects that have 'retained' and ownership interest in an object drops to 0 (i.e. when the last of the owning instances sends a `-release` message), the instance with a 0 retain count is deallocated.

It's sometimes convenient to say "I want this instance to be released *some time in the future*". That's the purpose of `-autorelease`. Sending an `-autorelease` message adds the receiver to the current `NSAutoreleasePool`. When that pool is drained, it sends a `-release` message to all the instances in the pool. An `NSAutoreleasePool` is automatically created at the start of each iteration of each thread's run loop and drained at the end of that iteration. Thus, you can do something like this in a method:

```
- (id)myMethod {
  return [[[MyObject alloc] init] autorelease];
}
```

The caller of this method will get back an instance that they can `-retain` if they wish to keep it. If they don't retain it, it will stick around at least until the enclosing autorelease pool is drained:

```
- (void)someOtherMethod {
...

id instance = [obj myMethod];
... // do more with instance, knowing that it won't be dealloc'd until after someOtherMethod returns

}
```

Comment: the link to the memory management programming guide appears to be broken; the iOS version can be found now at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html

Answer (score 11):

Releasing means you release that right away.
Autoreleasing means you want the variable to be released on the next autorelease pool.

You use autorelease when you want to keep retaining the variable but don't want to create a memory leak. You use release when you don't need the variable anymore.

Sample:

```
- (NSNumber *)return5 {
    NSNumber * result = [[NSNumber alloc]initWitnInt: 5];
    [result autorelease];
    return result;
}
```

Why do we use autorelease there?

If we use [result release] instead, variable result will be destroyed AT that time. Which means that the returned value will be garbage.

If we do not release at all, variable `result` will be hold FOREVER incurring memory leak.

We can tell every caller to the function to release result but that would be a headache and prone to error.

So we use autorelease. We mark the variable to be released on the next autorelease pool. Basically we mark the variable to be released near the alloc. Hence the mantra alloc is paired with release in the same function holds all the time.

Actually, you'll do fine changing all release into autorelease. Your memory use won't be efficient, however, the effect is minimal. All variables, in all programming language is effectively autoreleased.

Anyway, use ARC.

Answer (score 4):

background discussion:

objective-c is reference counted, so objects are deleted when the reference count reaches 0. release reduces the reference-count immediately, autorelease reduces it when the autorelease-pool is popped

when to use:

use autorelease when allocating the object if

- you do not need it after the current function
- it will be retiained by some other objet/function and will be released by a later by the retaining code
- when the logic of the current function is tricky, so you would have to send release in a dozen different places before doing a return

use "manual" release

- to revert a previous retain (in case you are implementing a library)
- if you need precise control of freeing objects (e.g. they use lots of memory or the autorelease pool will not be popped for some time)

but really my freand:

- read the [Memory Management Programming Guide for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447) as suggested by Barry and run your code with instruments (zombies and leaks) often to catch any and almost all memory management errors.

Erik

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Memory Management Programming Guide for Cocoa](https://web.archive.org/web/20100127080717/http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html):

> The autorelease method, defined by
>   NSObject, marks the receiver for later
>   release. By autoreleasing an
>   object—that is, by sending it an
>   autorelease message—you declare that
>   you don't want to own the object
>   beyond the scope in which you sent
>   autorelease.

Also:

> The autorelease method thus allows
>   every object to use other objects
>   without worrying about disposing of
>   them.