# Autorelease and release function

Tags: iphone

what's the difference beetween Autorelease and release function.
??can u give me example of autorelease function.

Comment: You have 19 questions, none of which you have marked as answered. As a courtesy to your fellow Stack Overflow users, please go through your old questions and mark them as answered where people took the time to help you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [release and autorelease? what is the difference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076402/release-and-autorelease-what-is-the-difference)

Answer (score 3):

Please read Apple's [Memory Management Guide for the iPhone](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/memorymgmt/memorymgmt.html). All your questions will be answered there.