# Do UINavigationController buttons added need to be autoreleased? is this code ok?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-management, uinavigationcontroller

Do UINavigationController buttons added need to be autoreleased?  is this code ok?

Background - I'm seeing a range of navigation issues occuring in my application after I start triggering "memory warnings".  I'm wondering if it is something to do with the question I posed here.  Questions would include:

1. Is code below correct?
2. Any additional memory management code required elsewhere?  (e.g. dealloc method? - I've currently got no code here to deallocate any buttons)
3. Any other tips re what might be going wrong with navigation bar populations/screen flow issues using a UINavigationController after simulating memory warnings

Code Below:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [ 
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addAction:)] autorelease];   // IS AUTORELEASE HERE CORRECT?
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;  
    self.title = @"Views";
```

thanks

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that code because the navigationItem will retain the UIBarButtonItem you are initializing there, so once it has been autoreleased, it won't be released from memory just yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always just use autorelease and I think that it should do just fine.

Answer (score -1):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIBarButtonItem *rightBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addAction:)];   // IS AUTORELEASE HERE CORRECT?
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButton;
[rightBarButton release];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;  
    self.title = @"Views";  
}
```

Comment: This answer offers no actual difference to the original code. Autoreleasing an object on the same line is functionally the same as creating, setting and releasing. Perhaps if you expand your answer to explain why you think this is a better approach, rather than just dumping some code, I'll reconsider my down-vote.

Comment: @Jasarien always manual release is better than autorelease  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076402/what-is-the-difference-between-releasing-and-autoreleasing

Comment: I disagree. Manually releasing is not always better. In this particular example, its no different. It's highly unlikely that autoreleasing will cause any perceivable difference to manually releasing because there is no tight loop involved or anything else that may cause the run loop to not empty the autorelease pool for a long period of time. Autoreleasing is a very useful and powerful pattern that shouldn't be discouraged based on the fact that manual releasing is "better", as you put it.