# what is the difference between release and auto release and is there any way to create a user defined autorelease pool?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between releasing and autoreleasing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076402/what-is-the-difference-between-releasing-and-autoreleasing)

Hi can you please elaborate what is the difference between release and auto release and is there any way to create a user defined autorelease pool?and the real use of auto release pool.

Comment: Not quite an exact duplicate of either of those questions, this includes the topic of how you create your own pool.

Answer (score 4):

Release reduces the object's reference count immediately, which means that if its retain count reaches zero it'll be immediately deallocated. Autorelease is a delayed release -- it's useful for ownership handoffs.

Consider a method like `+[NSString stringWithFormat:]`. It creates a new `NSString` instance (with `alloc` & some form of `init`) and then hands it off to the caller. That class method doesn't want to still "own" the created string after that, but if it releases the new string before returning, the new string will get deallocated before the caller gets it. Instead, it autoreleases the new string: that means the string will stick around long enough for the caller to grab it and retain it if needed.

What happens if the caller doesn't retain it? That's where autorelease pools come into play. The `NSAutoreleasPool` keeps track of every `autorelease`, and when told to drain, it releases all the objects in its pool (causing them to get deallocated if their reference count goes to zero). By default in a Mac or iOS app, there's an autorelease pool in the main event loop -- so if you call `stringWithFormat:` and don't retain the result, it'll go away on the next pass.

You can create your own autorelease pool with `NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init]` and drain it with `[pool drain]`. This can be useful if you have a section of code where you're creating a lot of temporary objects.

Comment: In modern code, one should use the `@autoreleasepool` statement instead of creating NSAutoreleasePool objects. You can't screw up an `@autoreleasepool` by accidentally not releasing it—it *will* end when the code says it will. Moreover, modern code should really use ARC rather than retain/release (it's the default for a reason); with ARC, the `retain`, `release`, and `autorelease` methods and the NSAutoreleasePool class all go away, and the compiler Does The Right Thing for you.

Answer (score 0):

`release` releases the object immediately while `autorelease` does it some time in the future.

**Example:** You'd want to return an `autorelease`d object here, because if you'd `release` it, it would already get dealloc before the code calling this method can make use of the returned object!

```
- (NSObject *)someMethod
{
    return [[[NSObject alloc] init] autorelease];
}
```

Comment: can you please tell me when this object autorelease happends? since I am not calling any release how apple identifies that the scope of object came to an end?

Comment: @harikrishnan: The autorelease (adding it to a pool) happens immediately. The pool releases the object when the pool itself gets released/drained. That happens either when you do it yourself (to a pool you created) or when you return to the application's event loop.