# Return Statement Creates and Release an Object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, object, return

I'm working someone else's code. I've never encountered something like this before:

```
return [[[NSObject alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Can someone tell me what this means and why someone would use it? Just to be clear, I'm not asking about the autorelease portion. I would have the same question about this code:

```
-(id)someMethod
{
lots of lines of code
...
return [[NSObject alloc]init];
}
```

Comment: Simple answer: Use ARC, you would never have to worry about this again.

Comment: That's simply wrong, Richard. With ARC, you must still be aware of how Objective-C memory management works, but once you know, you don't have to do as much manual labour.

Comment: Maybe returning `nil` in that method was reserved for signalling an error and they wanted to return something different for success but didn't really care what. Either way, bad design.

Comment: ...or maybe they wanted to return something that doesn't respond to any selector from some protocol. It's impossible to tell given one almost meaningless line of code.

Comment: @Lvsti returning an object from a message/function does not necessarily indicate bad design, it is something that is common to some Cocoa/Touch and Foundation libraries

Comment: @jshin47 sure, but returning an object just for the sake of returning something is pretty hard to justify IMO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just returning an autoreleased object for convenience. This means that when you use the function you do not have to append `autorelease` message to it generally speaking. You may always want certain objects to be autoreleased.

As an example, many of the included convenience ("factory") methods in Objective-C return an autoreleased object. You are probably familiar with `[NSString stringWithFormat:__FORMAT__]` which returns an autoreleased `NSString`. Take a look at http://memo.tv/archive/memory_management_with_objective_c_cocoa_iphone

As an example of why a function might return an object, consider a synchronous URL request, where you may or may not care about a response, or a function like the following:

```
- (NSString *)modifyObject:(MyObject *)o {
    o.mySettableProp = @"MODIFIED!";
    return [o description];
}
```

Comment: why return a newly created object in a function? This line of code is after a many line long function?

Comment: For example, a synchronous URL request typically will return a URL Response object. You may or may not care about the response (normally you do, but maybe you are just firing a shot in the dark). So you could either do `[request send]` or `response = [request send]`.

Answer (score 1):

The autorelease feature indicates that you want to release this object in the FUTURE, but not now because you still need to access it. With the release cycles and releasing of the pool of memory, autorelease is an extremely useful tool in memory management.
You can refer to: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447 for information on autoreleasing.
Here's a link! [What is the difference between releasing and autoreleasing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076402/what-is-the-difference-between-releasing-and-autoreleasing) 
Hope this helped!

Answer (score 1):

The object is being allocated, initialized and then added to an [autorelease pool](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html).

Quoting Apple documentation (the link above):

> Autorelease pools provide a mechanism whereby you can send an object a
>   “deferred” release message. This is useful in situations where you
>   want to relinquish ownership of an object, but want to avoid the
>   possibility of it being deallocated immediately (such as when you
>   return an object from a method). Typically, you don’t need to create
>   your own autorelease pools, but there are some situations in which
>   either you must or it is beneficial to do so.

TL;DR if nobody will `retain` the object soon, it will be released on the next iteration of the [run loop](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i).

It's hard to tell without knowing any details why would anyone want to allocate an NSObject in the first place. I'd suggest searching the project for that method's usage examples and see what happens with the object next.